# How can I redirect top-level routes but not child routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I need to redirect user to auth page if they aren't authorized. The redirect works fine.

So the question is how to redirect everything to one page, but not redirect subpages of this page?

For example i need to redirect user to '/auth' and then inside they can go to '/auth/signin' or '/auth/signup'.

Here is my code and it always redirect to '/auth'

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import {useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthView = () => {
     const {path} = useRouteMatch();
     return (
       <Switch>
          <Route path={`${path}/signup`}>
             <SignUp/>
          </Route>
          <Route path={`${path}/signin`}>
             <SignIn/>
          </Route>
          <Route path={`${path}/signout`}>
             <SignOut/>
          </Route>
       </Switch>
     );
}
const App = () => {
   return (
      <Router>
         <Switch>
            <Route path="/auth">
               <AuthView/>
            </Route>
            <Redirect from="*" to="/auth"/>
         </Switch>
      </Router>
   );
}
```

Update:
I solved it using this crutch, but I'm not sure, is it the proper way to solve it?

```
<Route render={(params) => { 
    if(params.location.pathname.match(/(\/auth)/)) {
       return;
    }
    return <Redirect to="/auth/signin/"/>
}}>
```

Comment: Did you try using the `exact` prop in the Route component? Try rendering all your routes like this
 `<Route exact path={`${path}/signup`}>  <SignUp/> </Route>`

Comment: What you have originally should work. The Redirect only happens if there is no match in the paths in the Switch (in App component), so the nesting does not matter to the Switch as long as "/auth" is matched.